# JAXB converts Java List to set of objects and thus loses list ordering

Tags: xml, json, jaxb, jaxb2, jettison

I have an XML schema for UI controls that looks something like the following XML

```
<InputParameters>
    <Combobox name="Combo1">...</Combobox>
    <Radiobutton name="Radio1">...</Radiobutton>
    <Combobox name="Combo2">...</Combobox>
    <Combobox name="Combo2">...</Combobox>
</InputParameters>
```

Here is how `InputParameters` (a field within another JAXB element) is declared:

```
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="InputParameters")
    @XmlElementRefs(
        {
            @XmlElementRef(name="Combobox",     type=ComboboxJAXB.class),
            @XmlElementRef(name="RadioButtonGroup", type=RadioButtonGroup.class)
        }
        )
    protected List<? extends InputComponent> inputParameters;
```

A few important points here:

- The order of items in `InputParameters` is important
- `Combobox` and `Radiobutton` all have the same substitution group head in the schema (`InputComponent`)

Might also be worth observing that:

- `InputParameters` can (and is) thought of as `Map` where the @name attributes are (unique) keys
- Since order is important, this would have to be a Java `LinkedHashMap`

The XML output from marshaling (shown above) is fine.   Where I'm having trouble is when JAX-RS outputs this as JSON.

In JSON, the output looks something like:

```
{
    InputParameters : {
       Combobox : {.....},
       Radiobutton : {.......},
       Combobox : {.....},
       Combobox : {.....},
       }
}
```

The problems here are:

- the `InputParameters` object has multiple properties named "Combobox"
- because `InputParameters` is an object rather than an array the order of items is not represented

The question boils down to this:  Can I get JAXB to output the content of `InputParameters` as an (ordered) array rather than an (unordered) set of objects?   Or perhaps there's just some very different approach I should consider?

The desired JSON output looks more like:

```
{
    InputParameters : 
      [
         {Combobox : {.....}},
         {Radiobutton : {.......}},
         {Combobox : {.....}},
         {Combobox : {.....}},
      ]
}
```

I am using the reference implementation of JAXB.